# Preventing changes in TimeObject's TimeZone with subsequent operations

Tags: date-and-time, units

Is there an option or method to lock TimeZone in TimeObjects? For example,

```
TimeObject[List[16, 22, 0.`], Rule[TimeZone, 0]] + 
  Quantity[1, "Seconds"] // FullForm
```

> TimeObject[List[9,22,1.`],Rule[TimeZone,-7.`]]

There is no way to set `TimeZone->Missing[]`, which is more appropriate for some tasks.

For example if the time zone when data was captured is unknown, Mathematica will still impute a TimeZone at the point of analysis, which also changes with Daylight Savings Time etc.

Merge, GroupBy and many operations used in data use exact equi-match semantics, resulting in no match with the same time but different TimeZones.

As per b.gatessucks, apparently this issue affects OSX only.

Comment: I get `TimeObject[List[16,22,1.`],Rule[TimeZone,0.`]]`, same as with `DatePlus[TimeObject[List[16,22,0.`],Rule[TimeZone,0]], {1, "Seconds"}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, 11.3?

Comment: Yes 11.3 indeed.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, I'm on Mac High Sierra, you?

Comment: Tried both Windows 7 and Linux (on wolframcloud).

Comment: I think this should be reported to WRI as it seems like a bug.  There seems no logic for adding a time quantity to a `TimeZone` object to result in changing the time zone.

Comment: @Edmund, reported to tech support.